# CKB Arch - Daemon run on startup

Tags: linux, arch-linux, startup, daemon

I have a Corsair K65 RGB Keyboard. To start it working, I had to clone https://github.com/ccMSC/ckb , compile and run the [clonedir]/ckb/bin/ckb-daemon . Every time I boot, I have to pull out my old keyboard and type in "sudo [clonedir]/ckb/bin/ckb-daemon". Is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install the package [from the AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ckb-git/) (and you really should use a PKGBUILD to install applications so they can be tracked by pacman), then you will be able to use the [systemd service file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd) provided with the package.

If you don't wish to go down that path, the service file is included in [the git repo](https://github.com/ccMSC/ckb/blob/master/service/systemd/ckb-daemon.service).

Once you have completed the install, you would simply:

```
systemctl enable ckb-daemon && systemctl start ckb-daemon
```